# Jhipster - Customize CRUD Interface

Tags: jhipster

Is there any way to change the code that generate CRUD interface in Jhipster .

What we trying to do is : we need to add new buttons in all CRUD interfaces , and changing some layout design .

So please guide me how to do that if that possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible at generator level unless you want to fork it, maybe in the future when blueprints get implemented.

So now, you just generate code and modify it manually and when you will run `jhipster upgrade` to keep up with JHipster's evolutions, the upgrade generator will use git to merge you manual changes with generated code.